# Validar si solo se selecciona un archivo en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validación, fileupload

Quiero validar un campo tipo `file` que no es requerido, pero solo si se ha seleccionado un archivo valide el tipo y el tamaño

Esto es en mi controlador:

```
if($request->hasFile('File')){
     $file = $request->file('File');
     $name = date_format($date,'Y-m-d').'_'.explode(' ',$emp->LastName)[0].'_'.explode(' ', $emp->Name)[0].'_'. $file->getClientOriginalName();
     $path = Storage::putFileAs('test_img', $file, $name);
  }else{
     $path = null;
}
```

Comment: Deberías utilizar FormRequest para realizar las validaciones y mantener limpio y sencillo el controlador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propongo crear un `FormRequest` para las validaciones respectivas, con el comando

```
// reemplazar Model por el nombre del modelo el cuál validará
php artisan make:request ModelFormRequest
```

a partir de esto, generar las reglas, donde la más importante sería un `if` simple dentro de `rules` *(método que genera el comando , además por el momento retornar true en el método authorize)*

```
public function rules()
{ 

 $rules = [
    'uncampo' => 'required',
    'otrocampo' => 'required|min:5',
  ];
  // Si el campo File se selecciono un archivo realizamos las validaciones
  // respectivas como el tamaño y el tipo 
  if ( $this->hasFile('File') )
  {
    $rules['File'] = ['max:2000','mimes:pdf,docx,doc'];
  }
  return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Para mi el agregar ese if fue una solución muy buena.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una validación con un Validator en tu controlador para validar el archivo recibido, puedes especificar que tipo de archivo o que tamaño necesites.

```
    $file = $request->file('File');
    $validator = Validator::make(
                        array(
                            'file' => $file,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'file' => 'file|max:5000|mimes:pdf,docx,doc',
                        )
                    );
//Si no pasa la validacion realizas una accion
  if ($validator->fails()) {
       return Redirect::to('miruta');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que simplemente deberías agregar la regla **nullable** a tu validación del campo FILE.

```
 'file' => 'nullable|file|max:5000|mimes:pdf,docx,doc'
```

Comment: No funciona sigue mostrando el mensaje 'File.image'=>'Formato No valido' aunque no se seleccione ningun archivo

Comment: Puedes probar esto? Reemplazando `nullable` por `sometimes`